# Why signing in Apps via OAuth ROPC flow is not recorded in AAD sign-in logs?

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

When I use ROPC (Resource Owner Password Credential) flow in my App to let users to sign in my App, why I cannot see any sign-in logs in AAD with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROPC is defined in OAuth2 protocol: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3 and it’s not included in OpenID Connect.
It just likes other flows in OAuth2, they’re designed for protecting API resources, not authenticating users.

**The behavior of [ROPC in AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc):**

For the ROPC flow, user inputs his/her AAD username and password in the client app side. Then the client sends the user’s credential to AAD. It shows as this below picture:
[image]

This behavior may cause a main risk: The client may store and upload the user’s AAD credential and used it for other things.  It can play as a **phishing app** to obtain user’s AAD credential.

Generally, in claims-based authentication, clients should just obtain a user’s attributes(E.g. claims in OIDC id_token, SAML token) issued by a trusted IDP to identify the user. Client shouldn’t obtain the user’s credential for other Identity providers.

**Why it’s still supported in AAD?**

We can see lots of our customers want to use ROPC flow to delegate user permissions to run a job automatically. Some of our customers use ROPC for their own customized login experience.
From Microsoft side, AAD supports ROPC flow as we can really understand it’s necessary in some special scenarios.

**So, what kind of app we can use ROPC in it?**

1. All client apps should be public client(Native App) first.
2. In Microsoft 1 party Apps, like Powershell.
3. In User’s owned/trusted Apps.

**How can we avoid being phished by a 3rd party app which prompts AAD login?**

- Make sure the page prompts you to input your AAD user credential is AAD login page. You can also check the domain in the URL. It should be start with “https://login.microsoftonline.com/”.
- Generally, we shouldn’t input the username and password together in one form. If a 3rd party app asks you to input your AAD username and password in one form, you need to be careful and don’t try to login it via your AAD credential here. Because AAD doesn’t provide any login page to let you enter your user credential in one form currently.

Overall, user login via ROPC flow may be a sign-in event for the client but it’s not a sign-in event for AAD as the user is not signed in AAD.